# How to change this query so that it will work no matter what data is present in database

Tags: mysql

At any time i need to get only 5 Records from the Database and this is my query

This is my data

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `historical_data` (
  `symbol_name` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `current_day` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `open_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `high_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `low_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `close_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prevclose_val` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;




INSERT INTO `historical_data` (`symbol_name`, `current_day`, `open_val`, `high_val`, `low_val`, `close_val`, `last_val`, `prevclose_val`) VALUES
        ('TATAELXSI', '2015-12-01', 2036.00, 2058.00, 1983.00, 2004.95, 2002.55, 2031.70),
        ('TATAELXSI', '2015-12-02', 2002.00, 2012.00, 1961.30, 1970.15, 1969.00, 2004.95),
        ('TATAELXSI', '2015-12-03', 1968.00, 2055.00, 1921.50, 1996.80, 1991.00, 1970.15),
        ('TATAELXSI', '2015-12-04', 1977.90, 2035.00, 1961.00, 1976.15, 1982.00, 1996.80),
        ('TATAELXSI', '2015-12-07', 1991.00, 2022.55, 1971.10, 1979.80, 1981.00, 1976.15),
        ('TATAELXSI', '2015-12-08', 1972.00, 2015.00, 1941.10, 1956.10, 1952.00, 1979.80),
        ('TATAELXSI', '2015-12-09', 1950.00, 1979.90, 1822.65, 1848.00, 1867.40, 1956.10),
        ('TATAELXSI', '2015-12-10', 1867.00, 1955.00, 1836.00, 1939.00, 1954.60, 1848.00),
        ('TATAELXSI', '2015-12-30', 2264.00, 2292.00, 2235.00, 2243.00, 2247.00, 2257.20),
        ('TATAELXSI', '2015-12-29', 2251.00, 2298.00, 2226.20, 2257.20, 2253.00, 2246.55),
        ('TATAELXSI', '2015-12-28', 2274.00, 2280.85, 2232.00, 2246.55, 2243.00, 2267.85),
        ('TATAELXSI', '2016-01-01', 2252.00, 2281.20, 2223.50, 2250.75, 2245.00, 2244.05),
        ('TATAELXSI', '2016-01-04', 2243.00, 2281.00, 2185.00, 2211.95, 2211.90, 2250.75),
        ('TATAELXSI', '2016-01-05', 2222.70, 2238.00, 2170.00, 2180.05, 2172.00, 2211.95),
        ('TATAELXSI', '2016-01-06', 2180.70, 2242.50, 2155.00, 2168.25, 2172.00, 2180.05),
        ('TATAELXSI', '2016-01-07', 2134.30, 2145.00, 2075.00, 2083.50, 2080.00, 2168.25),
        ('TATAELXSI', '2016-01-08', 2103.00, 2124.00, 2039.00, 2052.25, 2040.00, 2083.50)
```

And my sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f9c1b/2

```
SELECT * FROM historical_data WHERE symbol_name= 'TATAELXSI' and  current_day BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY) AND NOW() order by current_day asc
```

The above query works well if there are records for the Stock (means there is no holiday for market ) it fetches 5 records , in case if its monday (as theer is no data for sat and sun)

i need to use  (Changed the interval from 5 to 7 days )

```
SELECT * FROM historical_data WHERE symbol_name= 'TATAELXSI' and  current_day BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() order by current_day asc
```

My question is ,is it possible to makeit work no matter what data is present in database

Comment: Do you want `null` for date that does not exists in db? `TATAELXSI   date NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL ...`

Comment: what's the final result you are looking for?

Comment: I didn't quite get what you want. Can you show what would be your desired result from your sample? And what you mean by "to makeit work no matter what data is present in database"

Comment: last 5 records of the data present inside database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the last 5 days worth of data, sorted in ascending order.  You can do this with a subquery and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT hd.*
FROM (SELECT hd.*
      FROM historical_data hd
      WHERE symbol_name = 'TATAELXSI' and 
            current_day BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY) AND NOW()
      ORDER BY current_day DESC
      LIMIT 5
     ) hd
ORDER BY current_day ASC;
```

Strictly speaking the comparison on `current_day` is not needed in the `WHERE` clause.  But, this limits the amount of data being considered, which should benefit performance.

Comment: thanks a lot ,  was looking for this query only , thank you once again .

Answer (score 1):

if all you want is to get rid of results of Sunday and Saturday, you can use `weekday()` function to get the day and filter them out:

```
SELECT * FROM historical_data WHERE symbol_name= 'TATAELXSI' and  current_day 
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() 
AND WEEKDAY(current_day) not in (0,6)
order by current_day asc
```